# SQL - Selecting groups of rows that share a common value

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to retrieve accounts that shared the same ip.

For example, given the following table of logins:

```
acc ip
1   a
2   b
3   a
4   c
5   d
6   e
1   f
4   b
```

I want to get something like:

```
acc ip
1   a
3   a
2   b
4   b
```

Comment: This makes very little sense.

Comment: @popovitsj seems as though OP is looking for rows that have an `ip` count of > 1

Comment: Try to be more specific with your question.  Are you looking to get all the ip's that match some criteria (with their corresponding acc), or all the acc's that match some criteria (with their corresponding ip)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT acc, ip
FROM YourTable
WHERE ip IN (SELECT ip
             FROM YourTable
             GROUP BY ip
             HAVING COUNT(*) > 1)
ORDER BY ip, acc
```

[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/88fa7/6)

Comment: I did that while you were editing your comment to suggest it.

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways to do this. Here is a simple JOIN version;

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.* 
FROM mytable a
JOIN mytable b
  ON a.ip = b.ip 
 AND a.acc<>b.acc
ORDER BY a.ip, a.acc;
```

[An SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/88fa7/1).

It basically joins the table with itself to find rows with the same IP and another account.
DISTINCT is used to get each account/ip combination to show up only once.

Answer (score 0):

something like this? just order the letters alphabetically

```
SELECT acc, ip 
FROM table 
WHERE ip IN(    
    SELECT ip FROM table 
    GROUP BY ip HAVING count(ip) > 1
    ) ORDER BY ip, acc
```

Comment: Definitely not. You should try it yourself.

Comment: What does ordering have to do with the question?

Comment: looks like the OP wants it ordered in alphabetical order

Comment: No, he wants to select only the IPs that are duplicated.

Comment: Oh i misread that.. the question was not clear as it did not ask that.

Comment: What did you think "shared the same ip" meant? I agree that it's not very clear by itself, but the example clarified it for me.

Comment: @Barmar Ok i fixed the answer this will provide the correct results... like I said i misread that

Comment: Now your answer is just a copy of all the other correct answers.

Comment: true... although I wasn't even looking at the other answers and was building a fiddle to produce the correct result..

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT acc, ip
FROM tablename
WHERE ip IN (
    SELECT ip
    FROM tablename
    GROUP BY ip
    HAVING COUNT(acc) > 1)
ORDER BY ip ASC, acc ASC
```

Comment: Run this query and see if you get the desired result.

Comment: It continues further to get the other ips, but yes, this absolutely produces the indicated results. Based on the information we have been given, this answer is correct.

Comment: The question asks for accounts that "shared the same ip". Your solution doesn't look for any sharing.

Comment: your having should be counting ip not acc

Comment: @JohnRuddell Unless you use `DISTINCT` or the value can be `NULL`, it doesn't matter what you count.

Answer (score 0):

I find it hard to think of a scenario in which this is useful, but this is it:

```
SELECT acc, ip FROM table1 t
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE ip = t.ip AND acc != t.acc);
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
SELECT acc, ip 
FROM mytable 
WHERE ip IN (SELECT ip FROM mytable GROUP BY ip HAVING COUNT(ip)>1)
ORDER BY ip, acc
```